# Stripe redirectToCheckout - create firebase user after successful payment

Tags: reactjs, firebase, stripe-payments

I have a form which allows the user to create their firebase account and then redirect to Stripe to process payment. I am using the Stripe Firebase Extension.

Currently regardless if they complete payment the account will be created.

What I want to do is allow them to enter their email and password, redirect them to Stripe for payment, and then activate this account to allow login if payment is successful.

```
firebaseConfig.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.value, password.value)
          .then(id => {
            if (id) {
              const data = {
                id: id.user.uid,
                email: id.user.email,
              }
              firebaseConfig
                .firestore()
                .collection('user')
                .doc(id.user.uid)
                .set(data)
                .then(() => {
                  createCheckoutSession(id.user.uid)>
                });
```

My createCheckoutSession function:

```
import firebase from "../../config"
import getStripe from "./initializeStripe";

export async function createCheckoutSession(uid: string) {
  const firestore = firebase.firestore();

  const checkoutSessionRef = await firestore
    .collection("customers")
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("checkout_sessions")
    .add({
      price: "price_1KZ3nTGxUje7SlyIDUfIXkr3",
      success_url: window.location.origin,
      cancel_url: window.location.origin,
    });

  checkoutSessionRef.onSnapshot(async (snap) => {
    const { sessionId } = snap.data();
    if (sessionId) {
      const stripe = await getStripe();
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
    }
  });
}
```